# Python separate objects using copy method

Tags: python-2.7, copy

every one. I was trying to use the method copy(), but I was really frustrated it seems that there was bug within my program. I was supposed to get ct=99 only instead of ct =0, when comparing c1 and c2, but it turns out there are so extra terms behind. 
Just run the code , and you can immediately spot What that weird thing is. Thank you every one.

NB: This problem is a generic programming problem and has nothing to do with Fourvector.

```
import numpy as np

class FourVector:
    """ This document is a demonstration of how to create a class of Four vector """

    def __init__(self, ct=0, x=1, y=5, z=2, r=None):
        self.ct = ct
        self.r =  np.array(r if r else [x,y,z])
    def __repr__(self):
        return "%s(ct=%g,r=array%s)"% ("FourVector",self.ct,str(self.r))
    def copy(self):
        return FourVector(self.ct,self.r)

c1=FourVector(ct=0,r=[1,2,3]) # Note: c1,c2 here are objects, we used __repr__ to make them printable
print c1
c2=c1.copy() #use method copy within object c1
c2.ct=99
print c2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are copying, you are passing two unnamed arguments to `FourVector.__init__`. Python interprets them positionally, so you are effectively calling:

```
FourVector.__init__(new_self, ct=self.ct, x=self.r, y=5, z=2, r=None)
```

`r` is still `None`, so `new_self.r` is assigned to be `np.array([self.r, y, z])`. This is why the array in `c2` has extra terms.

Instead, you need to tell Python that the second value should be for the `r` argument, not just the second argument:

```
def copy(self):
    return FourVector(self.ct, r=self.r)
```

Alternatively, you could either re-order the arguments:

```
def __init__(self, ct, r=None, x=1, y=5, z=2):
```

or even remove the `x`, `y` and `z` arguments and provide them as the default value for `r`:

```
def __init__(self, ct, r=[1,5,2]):
```